# Google Play Consoles 100% Staged Rollouts not the same as Full Release?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

It seems Google Play Consoles 100% Staged Rollouts is not the same as a Full Release.

I released my app (version 1) a while ago.

The first update (version 2) rolled out with 20%, later updated to 50, then 100%. Today I released version 3 (again as a staged rollout), and recognised the previous release (version 2 with 100% staged rollout) is shown as "rollout stopped". When I view my app in the Store it is listed as version 1 - not as version 2 as i expected.

As it somehow seems to not be the same:

How do I convert a staged rollout that reached 100% to a full release?

---

Edit: More details

V2 got released (Step 2) and as it worked as intended i upped it to 100% (Step 3-4)

Now V3 is done. I created a release and rolled it out to 20%, expecting to get Step 5a, but got 5b, where new users would get an older version of my app.

How do i change the "Primary" version from V1 to V2, to get state (5a) the I expected?

[image: Version steps]

What my App-Releases view in the Play Console looks like (German UI):
[image: App-Releases view in the Play Console]

Comment: We am still stucked with the same issue. We have been trying to fix this issue with all possible cases but no luck. Did you find any solution for this issue? Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[The help documents are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149).

"Rollout stopped" means you halted a staged rollout. This prevents any more users getting the staged rollout, even if the percentage is 100%. You should only normally do this for an emergency fix situation, when your staged rollout shows you you are breaking users.

To get a rollout out of the "rollout stopped" state see section "Resume a staged rollout" in the help documentation:

> Using the Play Console website
>
> - Sign in to your Play Console.
>
>   - Select an app.
>   - On the left menu, click Release management > App releases.
>   - For the release that you want to resume, click Resume roll-out.
>   - Select a percentage.
>   - Click Update.
>
> Using the Play Console app
>
> - Open the Play Console app Console app.
>
>   - Select an app.
>   - On the 'Active releases' card, tap the track for the release that you want to halt.
>   - Tap Staged roll-out > Resume roll-out > Resume.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I still couldn't figure out how to solve my problem. As there were no problems with my Version 2 I rolled it out to 100%. Now with Version 3 coming i rolled that out to 20% - this seems to have stopped the rollout of V2, leading to a state where 80% of the users get the older Version 1. How can change it in a way that Version 2 is the "Store version"? I edited my initial post for more details.

Comment: Maybe this could help someone, once you increase rollout to 100% it's considered as full release and the previous one is deactivated.