# Instead of showing Full rollout, Google Play Console is showing 100% Staged Rollout

Tags: google-play-console

I have released many versions of my app. Once I halted the staged rollout and replaced it with the new One. Since then whenever I update my rollout to 100%(Gradually Mostly 20%, 50%, and then 100%), It's still showing the 100% Staged rollout instead of the full rollout.

Because of this, whenever my app is in review. The Play Console shows the last stable version that is way older, not the one that is 100% staged rollout.

The issue is exactly the same as faced by one of the users which has not been answered yet.
[Google Play Consoles 100% Staged Rollouts not the same as Full Release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857494/google-play-consoles-100-staged-rollouts-not-the-same-as-full-release)

Comment: It sounds like you might be experiencing an issue with your Google Play Console account. I would recommend reaching out to the Google Play support team for assistance.

Comment: Already followed up with them, but no solution from their side. Anyway thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Got the solution. Changing the current release version's distribution country to all solved the problem. Initially it was distributed to all countries, Later we removed few countries from the list.  After that changes,  all staged rollout with 100% never showed ful lrollout. Once, we made these changes , it again start showing full rollout. Might help someone... Thank you!

Comment: yeap that was the same issue